# First class labels in C?

Tags: c, jvm, label

Hey I am wondering if anyone can help me with first class labels in C.

I currently am trying to read java bytecode from memory(FLASH Memory of an AVR device) and I want to treat each instruction as a label, and dispatch the instruction by using a goto statement and jumping to the appropiate label.

But the problem is the function I use to read the instruction from memory returns a unsigned byte.

```
u08_t nvmfile_read08(void *addr) {
  u08_t val;
  addr = NVMFILE_ADDR(addr);  // remove marker (if present)
  memcpy_P((u08_t*)&val, (PGM_P)addr, sizeof(val));
  return val;
}

instr = nvmfile_read08(pc);
```

So my question is how can convert instr into something like:

```
void *ptr;
ptr = &&instr;
goto *ptr;
```

And this code will then ideally jump to this label:(Assuming iload was the last instruction read)

```
iload:
   // Execute the iload jvm instruction.
```

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are willing to use GCC extensions, you can put labels int an array of 256 values and perform a computed goto. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches: a `switch` statement or an array of function pointers.

The cases of the `switch` can be named by enumerators, like this:

```
enum jvm_opcodes {
    push = 0,
    pop = 1,
    /* etc */
    blah = 254
};
```

Then the switch looks like this:

```
switch ( instr ) {
    case push: {
    } break;

    case pop: {
    } break;
}
```

An array of function pointers would dispatch directly to other functions without writing out a `switch`. It may be more convenient if the source code is spread over more files.

```
/* dispatch.c */

typedef void (*jvm_dispatch)(); /* function pointer type */
jvm_dispatch insn_dispatch_table[] = { /* define array */
    handle_push, /* opcode 0 */
    handle_pop, /* opcode 1 */
    /* etc */
};

insn_dispatch_table[ insn ](); /* call an entry from the array */

/* push.c */
void handle_push() {
}

/* pop.c */
void handle_pop() {
}
```